# Can you get the LLVM IR from a binary using tools like CLANG?

Tags: binary, clang, llvm, llvm-ir, decompiling

It is possible to disassemble a binary, consisting of 0s and 1s, into LLVM Intermediate Representation (IR) for code analysis? This process involves converting the binary executable into LLVM IR, which is a higher-level, human-readable representation of the code.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, a couple of tools should be easy to find using google.

Comment: Some examples: [mcsema](https://github.com/lifting-bits/mcsema), [llvm-mctoll](https://github.com/Microsoft/llvm-mctoll), [retdec](https://github.com/avast/retdec), [rellume](https://github.com/aengelke/rellume). There's many more, however.

Comment: @MartinFink This should be an answer.